# Hybrid auth with Yii causing a redirect loop

Tags: php, yii, hybridauth, hybridauthprovider

I am trying to implement twitter sign in on my website using hybridauth.
I know there is a hybrid auth plugin for Yii. I am not using it because last time I used I ran  into some problems. I am trying to implement the core version of hybrid auth.

I am calling

```
$hybridauth = new Hybrid_Auth( Yii::app()->params['hybridauth'] );
$adapter = $hybridauth->authenticate( 'Twitter');
```

But for some reason it redirects to `http://localhost/yiiauth/authtest/?hauth.start=Twitter&hauth.time=1350973441` , which causes a redirect loop.
Is there any way to solve this problem ? My hybrid auth configuration is as follows :

```
'params'=>array(

    'hybridauth'=>array(
        "base_url" => "http://localhost/yiiauth/authtest/", 

        "providers" => array ( 
            "Twitter" => array ( 
                "enabled" => true,
                "keys"    => array ( "key" => "mykey", "secret" => "mysecret" ) 
            ),
        ),


        "debug_mode" => false,

        "debug_file" => "",
    )
),
```

My hybridauth files are in `/protected/extensions/hybridauth` and I include the `Hybrid/Auth.php` in the top of the index.php file

Answer (score 3):

1. Hybrid Auth login for twitter and facebook requires a valid domain not localhost.
2. Your **base_url** in configuration file "hybridauth.php" should be set to "/hauth/endpoint" i.e. it must point to the endpoint. If you have removed index.php through .htaccess then use "/index.php/hauth/endpoint".
3. Set permissions of hybridauth.log in Logs folder to **writable**.

Reference Link: http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/userguide/Configuration.html

Comment: Log is very useful info. I had infinite loop because I didn't register for Google+ API in console and Hybrid Auth uses it to check user data. Found out thanks to the log.

Answer (score 1):

Did you noticed the base url in your config? Its where the callback is returned during auth and you must use live web domain to test it.

"base_url" => "http://localhost/yiiauth/authtest/",

Also twitter requires additional tokens to be created , i hope you have done that already.

I have working hybridauth on my test website: [www.bemployable.com](http://www.bemployable.com)