# HybridAuth is always redirecting to my index.php

Tags: php, authentication, hybridauth

I don't know if I'm too stupid or something similar but I have a problem with implementing the HybridAuth code into my webpage.

I've run `install.php` and followed [this](http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/userguide/Integrating_HybridAuth_SignIn.html) "tutorial" for a simple twitter login. The login itself is running well, but the code on the tutorial says that at the end there should be printed all the twitter info which is transfered from twitter over `HybridAuth` to my page.

But `HybridAuth` is always redirecting me to my `index.php` (the `base_url` which I have declared at the `install.php` file). I know that it works because at the adress bar the URL says something like `http://localhost/alpha/index.php?hauth.start=Twitter&hauth.time=1352184502` ... but yeah, there is no info printed or something similar, just my site-index is visible.

Is there a trick or something I've forgotten?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hybrid Auth don't requires a real domain for testing purposes. The mistake was just laying at the Twitter Dev-Channel where the App-Name has to be the same as the domain (in my example -> localhost).

But thanks for every tipp!

Answer (score 0):

Hybrid Auth login for twitter and facebook requires a valid domain not localhost.

You can find similar post and answer here: [Hybrid auth with Yii causing a redirect loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13024803/hybrid-auth-with-yii-causing-a-redirect-loop/13244719#13244719)