# HybridAuth "Tiny Social Hub" example redirecting to /hybridauth/?hauth.start=Facebook&hauth.time

Tags: php, facebook, oauth-2.0, hybridauth

I'm trying to figure out how HybridAuth works. I've installed it on my server as per instructions, added my developer key for Facebook, Google etc, however when i go to the "Tiny Social Hub" example:

```
www.mysite.org/inc/examples/social_hub/login.php
```

and click "Sign-in with Facebook", i get redirected to:

```
www.mysite.org/inc/hybridauth/?hauth.start=Facebook&hauth.time=1362314218
```

Similar with "Sign-in with Google":

```
www.mysite.org/inc/hybridauth/?hauth.start=Google&hauth.time=1362314279
```

And i just see the directly listing of `/inc/hybridauth/` which includes:

```
index.php
config.php
Hybrid/
```

What am i missing?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this. For anyone who might run into this problem, the fix was based on a response to the question [Hybrid auth with Yii causing a redirect loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13024803/hybrid-auth-with-yii-causing-a-redirect-loop), specifically the following point:

> Your base_url in configuration file "hybridauth.php" should be set to "/hauth/endpoint" i.e. it must point to the endpoint. If you have removed index.php through .htaccess then use "/index.php/hauth/endpoint".

I needed to adjust my base url from:

```
"base_url" => "http://mysite.org/inc/hybridauth/"
```

to:

```
"base_url" => "http://mysite.org/inc/hybridauth/index.php"
```

My guess is that the first url would work in most instances because index.php is usually the default directory page. Whereas I've configured Apache to use home.php on my server.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Apache, another solution would have been for you to tell it to recognize index.php as an index file.

Add the following in the relevant /etc/(httpd|apache2)/sites.enabled/ or httpd.conf file

> > DirectoryIndex index.php

Or, assuming apache is configured to allow .htaccess files, simply create an .htaccess file and put the above line in there.