# Hybridauth in yii won't redirect to google

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, yii, hybridauth

I've been trying to make [hybridauth](http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/) work in [Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/) with [hybridauth extension](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/hybridauth/).

Problem is that when I want to sign using google, it just redirects me to http://mywebsite.com/site/login.

I'm using htaccess to remove the "index.php" from the path, and also to have index.html as default (because I'm just testing the yii and don't want to show it yet) it looks like this:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
RewriteEngine on
# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Hybridauth extension is configured in config/main.php in modules section this way:

```
 'hybridauth' => array(
        'baseUrl' => 'http://'. $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/hybridauth',
        'withYiiUser' => false, // Set to true if using yii-user
        "providers" => array (
            "google" => array (
                "enabled" => true,
                "keys"    => array ( "id" => "xxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com", "secret" => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" ),
                "scope"   => ""
            )


        )
    ),
```

On google console I've created Client ID for web applications, redirect URIs is this:

```
http://mywebsite.com/hybridauth/default/callback?hauth.done=google
```

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13024803/hybrid-auth-with-yii-causing-a-redirect-loop):

> Your base_url in configuration file "hybridauth.php" should be set to
>   "/hauth/endpoint" i.e. it must point to the endpoint. If you have
>   removed index.php through .htaccess then use
>   "/index.php/hauth/endpoint".

I've tried to set the baseUrl in config to `http://'. $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/index.php/hybridauth` with no luck. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've forgotten that I've set the debug property of srbac module to false, so then unauthorized user can't access hybridauth. The hybridauth has to be allowed in srbac module so it could be accessible for everyone.

EDIT:
I couldn't find the hybridauth module in srbac control panel, I've just added it to allways allowed list, see my response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18450225/enable-access-to-module-for-unauthorized-users-in-yiis-srbac).