# Enable access to module for unauthorized users in Yii's srbac

Tags: php, yii, module, hybridauth

I'm trying to use [hybridauth](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/hybridauth/) extension in Yii. Without [srbac](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/srbac/) extension is everything fine, problem is that I need to enable access to this module for unauthorized users using it. I've tried setting property alwaysAllowed as stated in [srbac guide](http://srbac.googlecode.com/files/srbac_guide_1.2.pdf):

> The operations are named as
>   [ModuleId]/[Subdirectory].[ContollerId][Action]

like this:

```
'alwaysAllowed'=>array( //default: array()
            'SiteLogin','SiteLogout','SiteIndex','SiteAdmin',
            'SiteError', 'SiteContact','hybridauth@controllers.DefaultLogin'),
```

(my delimiter is @), it doesn't work. I've been debugging it and it seems that the Hybridauth controller (DefaultController) is not recognized as SBaseController in function _extendsSBaseController (modules/srbac/controllers/AuthItemController.php):

```
if ($cont instanceof SBaseController) {
  return true;
}
```

My Controller class is extending the SBaseController and it works for controllers which are not in a module, but not for this. I've also tried to directly extend the DefaultController with SBaseController with no luck.

How to set the module to be alwaysAllowed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added `hybridauth@DefaultIndex` and `hybridauth@DefaultCallback` to allways allowed list and now it works. The construction of this string can be seen in `srbac/Controllers/SBaseController.php` in function `beforeAction`:

```
$access = $mod . $controller . ucfirst($this->action->id);
```